# Terrible performance when expanding long polynomials in sympy

Tags: sympy, expand, simplify

following is my python code.
`k1`, `k2`, `k3`, and `k4` are long polynomials.  I want to verify that k1*k3+k2*k4==0 but when I write `(k1*k3+k2*k4).expand`, the program has no response for a long time.  However, when I write similar code in matlab (`expand(k1*k3+k2*k4)`), matlab gives the expected answer (0) in five seconds.  How do I get this answer in sympy?

```
from sympy import symbols,expand,simplify
u1,u2.u3=symbols("u1 u2 u3")
k1= -2*u2*u3*(2*u3*(2*u1 - 2*u2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))**2*(u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - sqrt(3)*u3**3 + u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + sqrt(3)*u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2)) - 2*(-u3**2 + (u1 - u2)**2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) + u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(-sqrt(3)*u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - u3**3 - sqrt(3)*u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2)))*(-u1*u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2)*(u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) + u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(sqrt(3)*u2**2*(u1 - u2) + u2*u3*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + u3**3 - sqrt(3)*u3**2*(u1 - 3*u2)) - u1*u3**2*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(u2**2*(u1 - u2) - sqrt(3)*u2*u3*(2*u1 - 3*u2) - sqrt(3)*u3**3 - u3**2*(u1 - 3*u2))) - (-2*u2*u3*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))**2*(u2**2*(u1 - u2) - sqrt(3)*u2*u3*(2*u1 - 3*u2) - sqrt(3)*u3**3 - u3**2*(u1 - 3*u2)) - (u2**2 - u3**2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) + u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(sqrt(3)*u2**2*(u1 - u2) + u2*u3*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + u3**3 - sqrt(3)*u3**2*(u1 - 3*u2)))*(-u1*u3*(2*u1 - 2*u2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) + u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(-sqrt(3)*u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - u3**3 - sqrt(3)*u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2)) + u3*(2*u1 - 2*u2)*(-u1*u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2)*(u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) + u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(-sqrt(3)*u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - u3**3 - sqrt(3)*u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2)) - u1*u3**2*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - sqrt(3)*u3**3 + u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + sqrt(3)*u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2))) + u3*(u3*(2*u1 - 2*u2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))**2*(u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - sqrt(3)*u3**3 + u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + sqrt(3)*u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2)) - (-u3**2 + (u1 - u2)**2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) + u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(-sqrt(3)*u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - u3**3 - sqrt(3)*u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2))))
k2= -(u2**2 - u3**2)*(2*u3*(2*u1 - 2*u2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))**2*(u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - sqrt(3)*u3**3 + u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + sqrt(3)*u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2)) - 2*(-u3**2 + (u1 - u2)**2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) + u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(-sqrt(3)*u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - u3**3 - sqrt(3)*u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2)))*(-u1*u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2)*(u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) + u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(sqrt(3)*u2**2*(u1 - u2) + u2*u3*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + u3**3 - sqrt(3)*u3**2*(u1 - 3*u2)) - u1*u3**2*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(u2**2*(u1 - u2) - sqrt(3)*u2*u3*(2*u1 - 3*u2) - sqrt(3)*u3**3 - u3**2*(u1 - 3*u2))) - (-2*u2*u3*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))**2*(u2**2*(u1 - u2) - sqrt(3)*u2*u3*(2*u1 - 3*u2) - sqrt(3)*u3**3 - u3**2*(u1 - 3*u2)) - (u2**2 - u3**2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) + u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(sqrt(3)*u2**2*(u1 - u2) + u2*u3*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + u3**3 - sqrt(3)*u3**2*(u1 - 3*u2)))*(u1*u3*(2*u1 - 2*u2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))**2*(u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - sqrt(3)*u3**3 + u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + sqrt(3)*u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2)) + u2*(u3*(2*u1 - 2*u2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))**2*(u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - sqrt(3)*u3**3 + u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + sqrt(3)*u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2)) - (-u3**2 + (u1 - u2)**2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) + u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(-sqrt(3)*u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - u3**3 - sqrt(3)*u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2))) - (-u3**2 + (u1 - u2)**2)*(-u1*u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2)*(u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) + u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(-sqrt(3)*u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - u3**3 - sqrt(3)*u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2)) - u1*u3**2*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - sqrt(3)*u3**3 + u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + sqrt(3)*u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2))))
k3= -u1*u3*(2*u1 - 2*u2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) + u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(-sqrt(3)*u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - u3**3 - sqrt(3)*u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2)) + u3*(2*u1 - 2*u2)*(-u1*u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2)*(u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) + u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(-sqrt(3)*u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - u3**3 - sqrt(3)*u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2)) - u1*u3**2*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - sqrt(3)*u3**3 + u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + sqrt(3)*u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2))) - u3*(u3*(2*u1 - 2*u2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))**2*(u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - sqrt(3)*u3**3 + u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + sqrt(3)*u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2)) - (-u3**2 + (u1 - u2)**2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) + u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(-sqrt(3)*u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - u3**3 - sqrt(3)*u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2)))
k4= u1*u3*(2*u1 - 2*u2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))**2*(u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - sqrt(3)*u3**3 + u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + sqrt(3)*u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2)) - u2*(u3*(2*u1 - 2*u2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))**2*(u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - sqrt(3)*u3**3 + u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + sqrt(3)*u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2)) - (-u3**2 + (u1 - u2)**2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) + u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(-sqrt(3)*u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - u3**3 - sqrt(3)*u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2))) - (-u3**2 + (u1 - u2)**2)*(-u1*u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2)*(u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) + u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(-sqrt(3)*u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - u3**3 - sqrt(3)*u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2)) - u1*u3**2*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2)*(-u2*u3*(-u2**2 + 3*u3**2)*(u3**2 - 3*(u1 - u2)**2) - u3*(u1 - u2)*(-3*u2**2 + u3**2)*(3*u3**2 - (u1 - u2)**2))*(u2*(u1 - u2)**2 - sqrt(3)*u3**3 + u3**2*(2*u1 - 3*u2) + sqrt(3)*u3*(u1 - 3*u2)*(u1 - u2)))
```

Comment: Indeed, sympy is written in pure Python, so performance isn't comparable with packages written in C or Fortran.  Nevertheless, `(k1*k3+k2*k4).simplify()` returns `0` after a few minutes.  Note that you are using `sqrt` without importing it.  For performance, it is important that you use sympy's `sqrt` and not e.g. `math.sqrt`.

Comment: thank you very much,I use 80 seconds to get the result in my win10 computer